# What kind of encoding is this URL?

Tags: url

A bunch of photos in a website directory has these URLs for each photo:

- www.example.com/3aecbc1bf32c7615fb732d407b1b571a.jpg
- www.example.com/27cbb6.jpg

My question is are the random gibberish part some kind of encoding that can be decoded? Or is each photo really represented by these random character strings? I wish to understand the pattern so I can guess the URL and view all the photos in the directory. Thanks.

Comment: It's hexadecimal.  I know that because the digits are 0-9, a-f.

Comment: Further, the first example is almost certainly the hex representation of a 128 bit GUID.  Each hex digit is 4 bits, and there are 32 of them.  Or, it could be an MD5 hash of the jpg.

Comment: In any case, one reason for using such a number is to *prevent guessing* of exactly the type you're describing.  To predict an MD5 hash, you would have to already have the original content (the jpg), and a GUID cannot be predicted in any practical way.

Answer (score 0):

That string looks to be an [md5 hash value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5#MD5_hashes). The result of an MD5 hash function will always be the same length, regardless of the length of the input string. The output is always 128 bits, or 32 characters.